# Data from a select to other page with foreach PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, select, foreach

```
<form action="poules.php" method="GET">
EOT;
   for ( $l = 1 ; $l <= $_GET['poule'] ; $l++ )
        {
            $body .= '<td>Poule '.$l.' :<br /><select name="panier[]" multiple="multiple" id="panier'.$l.'" size="8" style="width:90px;">
            <option value="tomato">1</option>
                            <option value="potato">2</option>
                            <option value="poro">3</option></select></td>';
        }
$body .= <<<EOT
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">

            <input type="hidden" name="poulos" value ="{$_GET['poule']}">
            <input type="submit" name="validate" value=" OK "/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And in the other page I have this :

```
foreach ($_GET['panier'] as $selectedOption)
{`enter code here`
    echo $selectedOption."\n";
}
```

And I wanted to output all the data of the select list in the other page "poules.php" but I dont know how to do it's written :

```
Notice: Undefined index: panier1 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: The value is always "tomato"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating a pile of HTML that looks like:

```
<td><select><option>...</option><select></td>
<td><select><option>...</option><select></td>
<td><select><option>...</option><select></td>
etc...
```

which is utterly useless. It should be

```
<td><select>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>...</option>
    etc...
</select><option>
```

In other worse, your loop should be

```
$body .= "<td><select>";
for(...) {
   $body .= "<option>...</option>";
}
$body .= "</select></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It works but i wanted to do it with different select box in one page Because with your code my select boxes disapear and i have only one select box